# Get server misbehaving error when trying to build an image in Minikube on Windows 10

Tags: minikube

I have installed Minikube and am following the "Hello minikube" tutorial:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/hello-minikube/#create-a-minikube-cluster

I have started minikube using the Hyperv driver:

> minikube start --vm-driver="hyperv" --hyperv-virtual-switch="New Virtual Switch" --alsologtostderr

When I try to build an image using the Minikube Docker daemon,  get the following error:

> Step 1/4 : FROM node:6.9.2
>
> Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 172.24.209.161:53: server misbehaving

**What is going wrong here, and how can I fix it?**

Here is some info about my environment:

minikube version: v0.23.0

OS: Windows 10 17_09

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear all Docker data. This has done the job to me ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just to confirm, by Docker data do you mean performing a "docker system prune"? Or should I delete dangling images or stopped containers as well? Also, I assume you are running this whilst connected to the Minikube Docker daemon?

Comment: I mean deleting all images and volumes. I have done it by Preferecnes->Reset->Remove all data. I think the problem is corrupted minikube dns image. I suggest to stop minikube before that operation ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you can build your images on the local machine then take a copy of 
  `/etc/resolv.conf`
and copy the values and insert into the minikube cluster's `/etc/resolv.conf`  using `minikube ssh` after all its just a VM and you are accessing the docker-engine/server using the environment variables..!!!

cheers :)